# Switched or linear charger IC for lead-acid battery - which one to pick?

Tags: battery-charging

What is the difference/practical consequence of using switched vs. linear charger controlling ICs and which one should I choose?

I understand that the switched regulators/chargers use a PWM while the linear ones use an adjustable voltage divider.

But how does that map on the practice? I need to charge a lead-acid (Yuasa 6V 1.2Ah) battery from the solar battery and I choose between TI's [linear UC2906](http://www.ti.com/product/uc2906) and a [switched UC2909](http://www.ti.com/product/uc2909).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linear regulators waste power because it is like using a variable resistor to control the charging current. Whatever current flows into the battery also flows thru the resistor and this generates heat.

A switcher wastes very little heat normally  and could be more than 95% efficient. Very useful for limited power output from a solar cell.

Comment: What is the argument for using the linear ones then?

Comment: Less EMI, simpler and can be tested with a simple meter springs to mind.